# Tire clearance on 2019 Trek Crockett

Tags: tire, trek

Has anyone tested max tire width on a Trek Crockett (2019 frameset)? Wondering specifically if I can fit 45mm tires on 19mm inner width rims.

Comment: On 622 rims I suppose?

Comment: To be clear this question is only asking about rim compatible with the desired tire width, and not about frame compatibly with that tire width? The question title implies the reverse.

Comment: Different tires (marked at the same size) can have slightly different fit characteristics with respect to the frame, particularly when you're near the limit of what will clear the frame. My guess is that 45c tires will not clear the frame or be too close for comfort (this is a judgement call; some people will run bigger tires than others will), but it is something you may need to try. Trek really wants to sell you the Checkpoint for 45c tires rather than the Crockett.

Comment: @Batman the 2018 Crockett only clears 700x40c tires, I would be surprised if this drastically changes for 2019.

Comment: @Rider_X - yeah. The checkpoint is advertised to max at 45c so id guess that the crockett should peak lower.

Answer (score -1):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwkOp.png]

Suggests that 19mm is the upper limit for 45mm tyres but should still work.

If you have any choice, 23mm wide rims would be better.  Depends if in the future you want larger than 45mm wide tyres, or smaller.

Comment: Not really a fan of that chart.  Whilst I appreciate its only supposed to be a guideline, its a long way off representative of the real world.
For example until the recent trend for wider rims XC MTB's have been shipping from manufacturers with 2.25" tyres on 17mm internal rims forever